# NTLDR Missing in Windows Server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003

How do you solve ntldr missing in windows server 2003 and can you rename a domain if so what is the procedure in windows server 2008

Answer (score 2):

This [Microsoft support](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816793) article describes troubleshooting `NTLDR is missing` errors.  It can be summarized as:

1. Use boot floppy to restore `ntldr`.
2. Use the [Recover Console](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326215).
3. Use the Windows 2003 install CD and choose "Repair".

You could potentially use a non-Windows boot disc to restore `ntldr`, provided the OS supported NTFS writes -- most Linux distros do now-a-days.

If your other question is about renaming an Active Directory domain -- it has been asked on SF [multiple](https://serverfault.com/questions/32660/renaming-a-windows-2003-domain) [times](https://serverfault.com/questions/171566/active-directory-domain-rename-versus-migration) already.  Not only should it be a separate question, but it is likely a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time when I get an 'ntldr machine', the system partition just needs a chkdsk.

Sometimes it does need a repair/reinstall after an infection.

Even rarer is a partition table or BIOS boot order change which leaves the boot order changed and boot.ini broken.

And once, an Adaptec RAID controller popped the hot spare as first hard disk in the boot order, because of a bug in combination with me putting the hot spare in as drive 0. Good luck :-)

Comment: How do you run `chkdsk` on the partition if you can't boot the OS? From a floppy?

Comment: Floppy? Have I fallen into a time hole? Just use a boot disc (as in: CDrom or DVD), or your favourite USB gizmo that boots your ISO images. Any run-of-mill Windows install image will do: go to command prompt or maintenance mode, and run chkdsk from the command line.